# Using VLANs on linux dummy interfaces

Tags: linux, bridge, vlan

I have an application that uses raw sockets to consume all packets from multiple linux (kernel 4.14) interfaces including wireless. In an attempt to keep extraneous scripting to a minimum, I'm trying to use hostapd to bind the wireless and bss interfaces to bridges with interfaces that my application listens to. I also have a use case where I need my application to receive traffic from the wireless on a specific VLAN (sorta like native vlan remapping). Presently, my setup looks like this:

- dummy interfaces are created for my application to bind to

```
ip link add dummy0 type dummy
ip link set dummy0 up
```

- as needed, vlan interfaces are created on the dummy interface

```
ip link add link dummy0 name dummy0.100 type vlan id 100
ip link set dummy0.100 up
```

- a bridge is created to tie the dummy to wlan, attaching dummy0 or the vlan as required. The application still only listens on dummy0

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 dummy0.100
ip link set br0 up
```

- hostapd attaches the wlan or bss interface to the bridge defined in hostapd.conf

When no vlans are involved, this works well. For vlan interfaces, I'm only able to get traffic going in one direction. tcpdump on dummy0 shows all traffic as I would expect it to. tcpdump on dummy0.100 and br0 only shows traffic from the wireless interfaces, but no return traffic.

I'm assuming the issue is that my application is writing raw frames with vlan tags to dummy0 instead of to dummy0.100 but I suppose it is also possible the issue is with using dummy interfaces themselves. Is there any way for me to use a raw socket on dummy0, write frames with vlan tags, and have them show up on dummy0.100 correctly? I'm also open to better solutions, but this requires the least setup and monitoring infrastructure.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106658/discussion-on-question-by-apschultz-using-vlans-on-linux-dummy-interfaces).

Answer (score 1):

As identified by @dirkt, RAW sockets may not be capable of directing packets to VLAN sub interfaces when bound to the root device. A reasonable solution suggested by @dirkt is to use a veth pair.

```
ip link add veth0-wifi type veth peer name veth0-app
ip link set veth0-wifi up
ip link set veth0-app up
ip link add link veth0-wifi name veth0-wifi.100 type vlan id 100
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 veth0-wifi.100
ip link set br0 up
```

Set bridge=br0 in hostapd.conf and bind the application to veth0-app

An alternative suggested by @A.B, unexplored for technical reasons, is to have the application publish a tap device which should allow mostly the same organization.